# Blank page after publish cordova app to app store

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, publish, windows-store

I have developed an app for Windows Phone 10 with Visual Studio 2015 in combination with Cordova. When I publish the app on a Windows Phone 10 the app works totally fine. But after publishing the app to the app store, the only thing I see is a blank page on the Windows Phone 10.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to debug this problem.

Gr. Chiel